# Capistrano: Deploy Laravel app on ubuntu server

Tags: deployment, capistrano3

I have an ubuntu staging server where I have installed apache, php, mysql, git, composer installed. I have a private git repository setup on the bitbucket, the project is already cloned to the staging server and to my local development machine. The Laravel setup is working perfectly fine on both machine.

What I am currently doing is whenever there is an update to the git repository, I do login to the staging server, pull the latest code from the git repository and do `composer install`, `npm install`, `bower install`.

I want to automate this process via capistrano tool. I checked the tutorials online, but all of them do the clone of repository whenever, I issue a deploy command and creates a fresh installation every time. Can't capistrano helps me to work on the existing folder that is already setup?

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise of Capistrano is the idea that a new installation is created each time, such that there is not much to be done initially in terms of setup. If you'd rather use a different mechanism, a different tool would work better for you! For such cases, you could try to write a script using SSHKit directly (fairly advanced), or write a makefile or some other tool to automate your process.

If you do want to try to make Capistrano work on its terms, look into how linked_dirs and linked_files work in it. They allow you to have some files (e.g. config files, log dirs, etc) which are outside of the deployment directory and as such are shared between deploys.